# ¿Cómo escribir en una parte específica de un fichero o documento, de manera dinámica?

Tags: php, fopen

Como proyecto de clase estoy intentando hacer un "gestor de contenido" muy pero muy simple, para que permita a una persona 'sin conocimientos web' agregar contenido en una pagina. El contenido, por ahora, seria simple texto plano, y el sistema para lograr esto serian los "ficheros" o "sistemas de archivos". La persona, en un panel de control, tendria un formulario para crear un articulo, con los campos de "titulo" y "contenido del articulo", ademas del boton de "publicar". Presionando el boton crearia un fichero o documento (que tomaria el nombre que la persona le dé al titulo de su articulo), y dinamicamente se copiaria el contenido HTML de otro fichero (que serviria de "plantilla") en el documento creado por el usuario (que asi tendria una estructura HTML incluida)..Luego de esto, al documento creado por el usuario se le agregaria el contenido insertado por él en la textarea.
Yo he conseguido hacer todo lo mencionado anteriormente, excepto lo de "lograr que la persona escriba en un lugar especifico del fichero"; exactamente necesito que el usuario inserte su contenido dentro del BOdy, dentro de un articulo (en un h1 el titulo, lo otro en parrafos). Pero hasta ahora solo consigo que lo inserte al final de la etiqueta HTML... Dejo mi codigo para ver si me pueden ayudar por favor:

```
            /*
            CREO DOS CAMPOS, 
            UNO PARA INSERTAR EL TITULO
            Y EL OTRO PARA EL CUERPO DEL ARTICULO.
            EL TERCERO ES UN BOTTON DE ENVIO
            */
            <form method="POST">
              <input type="text" name="titulo" placeholder="Título" /> <br />
              <textarea name="articulo" placeholder="Artículo"></textarea> <br />
              <input type="submit" value="Publicar" />
            </form>

        /*
        - SI EL USUARIO PRESIONA EL BOTON
        Y ENVIA CONTENIDO,
        SE EJECUTA LO SIGUIENTE:
        - SE CREA UN DOCUMENTO
        CON EL TITULO QUE EL USUARIO LE DÉ.
        - LUEGO SE COPIA EL CONTENIDO HTML
        DE UN DOCUMENTO LLAMADO "PLANTILLA"
        EN EL NUEVO DOCUMENTO CREADO POR EL USUARIO.
        - DESPUES SE ESCRIBE EN ÉL
        LO QUE EL USUARIO ENVIE POR LA TEXTAREA
        */
        <?php
        if ( isset( $_POST ) ) {
            $Op = fopen( $_POST['titulo'] . '.php', 'a+' );
            copy( '/home/PHP Y SQL/CMS/plantilla.php', '/home/PHP Y SQL/CMS/'. $_POST['titulo'] . '.php' );
            fwrite( $Op, $_POST['titulo'] . '<br>' . $_POST['articulo'] . '<br>' );
        }        
        ?>
```

Comment: Si usas el punto y aparte se agradece, para una mejor comprensión. En cuanto al problema planteado, creo que sería cuestión de organizar tu plantilla de modo que puedeas con toda libertad agregar lo que sea dinámico antes o después de agregar la plantilla, en vez de plantearte soluciones complicadas como poner la plantilla para luego tratar de inyectarle contenido dentro... eso no tendría demasiado sentido. O bien puedes poner un marcador único en la plantilla y luego reemplazarlo por el contenido que quieres ahí. Supongamos que tienes esto en tu plantilla: `<body>*</body>`, reemplazas `*`

Comment: Necesito un ejemplo por favor.......Tambien habia pensado en usar INCLUDE...que en un documento se agregue unicamente texto, y ese documento incrustarlo (con include) en una plantilla...pero seria demasiado complicado..tendria que crear dos cosas, un nuevo documento con el titulo que el usuario le dé, y el otro documento que va a ser incluido.